# C#. WPF. observablecollection how to get current items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

This is my collection :

```
ObservableCollection<CheckInData> _CheckInCollection = new ObservableCollection<CheckInData>();
public ObservableCollection<CheckInData> CheckInCollection
{
    get { return _CheckInCollection; }
}

public class CheckInData
{
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Currecny { get; set; }
    public string Discount { get; set; }
    public string CheckOut { get; set; }
    public string TotalDay { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public int CheckOutYear { get; set; }
    public int CheckOutMonth { get; set; }
    public int CheckOutDay { get; set; }
    public Boolean IncToday { get; set; }
    public string CheckIn { get; set; }
    public decimal MoneyRate { get; set; }
}
```

I have one class where i save export my collection this way:

```
foreach (CheckInData coll in CheckInCollection)
{
    var roomType = (from d in db.SelectRooms where d.roomnumber == coll.RoomNumber select d.roomtype).SingleOrDefault();
    inv._RoomType.Add(roomType.ToString());
    inv._RoomNumber.Add(coll.RoomNumber.ToString());
    inv._CheckIn.Add(coll.CheckIn);
    inv._CheckOut.Add(coll.CheckOut);
    inv._DayNight.Add(coll.TotalDay);
    inv._RoomPrice.Add(coll.Price);
    inv._Discount.Add(coll.Discount);
}
```

This code works perfectly. I have list view which is binding with this observable collection so my question is how i can insert into `inv._RoomType`, `inv._RoomNumber`... only that collection which(rows) are selected in `listview`. `inv._RoomNumber.Add(coll.RoomNumber(listview selected items? ??))` Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an IsSelected property to your CheckInData class and then bind to that from the ListView. You can then say

```
foreach (CheckInData coll in CheckInCollection.Where(s => s.IsSelected))
{
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. It was unclear for me. can you write code for that? :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I guess you have to get all selected item from the ListView UI control.

If so, ListView provides two properties: ListView.SelectedItem or ListView.SelectedItems, depending on whether you enabled multi-selection.

Let's assume you'd like to multi-select these items. Then the following code will help you with your question:

```
foreach(var item in listView.SelectedItems) 
    YourClass.Insert(item as CheckInData);
```